# I need C compiler to work with gotoxy(), wherex(), wherey() functions in windows7 64 bit OS

Tags: conio

what i tried is...
I am writing code to print all the c-language character set ASCII codes [0-255] along with characters (256)!
As we know in C, function declaration or header file declaration is optional!

```
void main()
{
  int i = 0;
  char c1, c2;

  printf("ASCII code\tCharacter\n");
  printf("----------\t---------\n");

  //printing
  while (i <= 255)
  {
    printf("%d\t%c\n", i, i);
    i += 1;
  }

  /*
   my code to move the cursor in console screen
   using up & down arrows!
   ASCII codes of up & down arrows are(0 & 72) & (0 & 80)
   when i press any other non-data key it comeout from program!
  */
  c1 = getch();

  while (c1 == 0)
  {
     c2 = getch();

    if (c2 == 72)//up arrow
       gotoxy(wherex(), wherey()-1);

    else if (c2 == 80)
       gotoxy(wherex(), wherey()+1);

    else //any other key
       break;

    c1 = getch();
  }
}
```

In turbo-C IDE i can able to see only last console screen, and i can able to move the cursor only within that 1 page console screen only!
What i need to do is i want to see from 0th ASCII onwards!

What i got in turbo-C IDE is...

[image: In Turbo-C IDE output: only 1 screen]

I am also using Borland-C++ 5.02 IDE.
In that IDE i can't even move the cursor!
But i am sure gotoxy(), wherex(), wherey() functions are working in that Borland-C++ IDE.
Because i allredy checked by writing a small piece of code only accepting arrow keys
and functions also worked properly.
Actually i am a new be for C/C++.
Just working out advanced level for my practise only!

Then, I have downloaded the following C/C++ IDE for my windows7 OS.

```
<Dev-C++ 5.4.0 verion IDE>.
```

In that IDE when i use these functions...

```
gotoxy(), wherex(), wherey()
```

Undefined reference to 'gotoxy', 'wherex', 'wherey' linker errors.

I saw a question in this site.
I was instructed to download  latest header file from http://conio.sourceforge.net/
and I got the same errors!

Can anyone suggest me?
i am just willing to write some funny and tricky console screen programs. 
**seeking help, for how to add external conio library for dev-C++ IDE or code-blocks IDE?
please provide me with fully in detail!
I must need the solution on other than turbo-C++ IDE, preferable DEV-C++ OR CODE-BLOCK-IDE FOR WINDOWS7 OS! giving links more help full for me! thanks in advance**

Comment: "function declaration or header file declaration is optional". Sure. But why do you think they exist? They make life easier, not harder.

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens when you use **non-ANSI** functions and you move to another compiler.

You evidently are compiling C code that came from DOS and the 
**Borland** compiler. These specific functions don't exist in **Unix**.

The ***Compiler*** that Dev-C++ uses is a **MinGW**. So you will need to add "**conio.c**" to your project and include it your headers

Comment: please review my question!

Comment: How to add? can you please tell me in detail?

Answer (score 1):

You need to link with the conio library. Add -lconio to the linker parameters under Project Options.

[image: The linker parameters]

If that doesn't work, make sure you have actually downloaded the conio library and put it in the right directory (you'll need the `conio2.h` file as well as the `libconio.a` file, which is the library itself).

Comment: Please review my question and tell me How to add? can you please clearly mention! I have downloaded the conio2.h here in that it clearly mentioned conio for Dev-C++ IDE. My OS is windows7. How to add external library?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows C file conio.h lacks the definition of those functions, but they can be defined.

You can find the functions you need here -> [Windows Console Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Here are the requested functions defined

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(short int x, short int y)
{
    COORD pos = { x, y };    
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), pos);
}

int wherex()
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;    
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);    
    return csbi.dwCursorPosition.X;
}

int wherey()
{
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;    
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);    
    return csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y;
}
```